# not to pop up a form on second click using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pop up form on my site which pops up as soon as some one click on the link. but I want to make it such that it should not pop up for the second time for a same user.

how to do it, as I don't have user management system.

Comment: save cookie for user

Comment: Set cookies & check cookies by setting flag for user in 'onclick' function, to check whether that user clicked once or twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better Solution,Use `one` in Jquery

```
<a id="popup" >link1</a><br>
$('#popup').one('click',function(){

 alert('open your popup here');
 });
```

Here is you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8c7hv3e/1/)

Comment: I am not able to use it or its not working properly. this is my html for link <a id="popup" onclick="div_show()">link1</a>, which has a pop-up contact form on click event. Now I don't want to pop up the form for same user.

Comment: You already answered one that means you have solved.If not,i would help further

Comment: can i do some thing else on second click?

Comment: "one" is for showing the "a" once, but what is the use of .click(function(){
  // Call B
    alert('b');
 });   if it clicked on the id I specified, both alert is coming up

Comment: If you do not need to use function b then remove it...I Updated my code...now it is exactly as your requirements...please mark as answer & up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookies for it. At first click, generate a cookies when user clicks at first time and checks if it's available when user click on it.

Answer (score 0):

So, as kind of solution u can use cookies. Example below.

This support function will help u get cookie using JS later

```
function getCookie(name) {
   var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,'\\$1')+"=([^;]*)"));
   var x = matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
   return x;
}
```

And than in user click handler set cookie for browser like this

```
$(document).on('click','#someDivHere',function() {
   if (getCookie('addShowed') === undefined) {
      var date = new Date( new Date().getTime() - 2*24*60*60*1000 );
      document.cookie="addShowed='true'; path=/; expires="+date.toUTCString();
   }
});
```

Comment: can you please explain how to use it on my link which is -----                         <a id="popup" onclick="div_show()">link1</a><br>